# Best Way to Handle a Elapsed Subscriptions

Tags: mysql

I have a column on my database called **SubscriptionDate.** Another column called **State**

"State" is to display Active if the subscription is still valid.

Now i was thinking of a way in which i could make the subscription valid and invalid by changing the **state** to those.

Is there a way in which i could put in a Datetime in **SubscriptionDate**, then do "something" to decrease this Datetime to Zero ? and if it's zero i set the column back invalid. Can this be done with some procedure or do i have to write some code in Java (which i am using) to do this.

Comment: How about just using a start and end date column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way is to simply put a `Start` and `End` date.

But if you want to go through with your idea, you can use [scheduled jobs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html) to decrease the `SubscriptionDate`

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to have 2 columns. `start_date` and `end_date`.